# Adding background image in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I decided to use inline JS styles in React. Everything is ok except images. Here I try to add a background image to div but I get errors.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

var styles = {
color:'violet',
backgroundImage: 'url(' + require('./sun.png') + ')' 
};

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <h1>How to make smth</h1>
        <div style={styles}>test</div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I get errors, and I just dont know what loader do i need and how to add it to the webpack config (or package.json)

[here is what i get](http://i64.tinypic.com/24ni99u.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import image from './sun.png';

var styles = {
color:'violet',
backgroundImage: 'url('+image+')'
};
```

Adding loaders:
In the webpack config you are using change

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties'],
        }
      }
    ]
```

to

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties'],
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        loader: "url-loader",
        query: { mimetype: "image/png" }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: It is looking like a nice solution.I tried but the same error:
Module parse failed. .... You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Same error as before

Comment: what is the bundler that you are using? Are you using create-react-app? or are you manually configuring the bundler?

Comment: I dont use create-react-app here. I use a custom config that I found on codeacademy and modified it little bit
https://github.com/mapledrive/config.git

Comment: I tried but the same error. I still need an appropriate loader

Comment: try `url-loader` with `{test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader'}`

Comment: I understand that my config lacks some loader for images that is available in create-react-app but I fail to understand what kind of package it is

Comment: I dont know where to add this url-loader into config

Comment: Updated the answer and added config change to add loader to your webpack config